# Image Could not be loaded - Wordpress issue

Tags: wordpress

I am having issue on my wordpress website. Where I have gallery plugin and the images in that gallery showing this error message when you click on the image. In past those used to pop up when you click on it. But currently it show this error message. I think there is some js conflict please help me here. screenshot- [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w0JYv.png)

webpage - http://www.marvelrealtors.com/residential-properties/izara/

Comment: Can't see on your link what you're referencing, and your question is too broad. THere's no extra info you can show? Have you contacted the plugin author (I'm assuming it's a plugin)

Comment: so sorry if it is confusing I have tried contacting plug in support (Owl Carousel) but no response. There is gallery and actual development section on this page. when you click on the image it shows error message as "The image # could not be laoded."

Comment: Have you checked your URLs?

Comment: Any solution? I am facing the same problem. I am using Doing Business Theme 50603 from Template Monster. The Grid Gallery Portfolio post has the same problem. Light Box is giving the error mentioned above. On a fresh local install, it works fine. What could be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

image url is missing in anchor tag. please check.

```
<a href="#" class="poppup">
    <img src="http://www.marvelrealtors.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/Izara-Dining-Room.jpg" title="Dining" alt="Dining" data-lazy-loaded="true" style="display: inline;"><noscript>&lt;img title="Dining" src="http://www.marvelrealtors.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/Izara-Dining-Room.jpg" alt="Dining"/&gt;</noscript>

</a>
```

Working script:

```
<a class="image-popup-no-margins boxed_shadow" href="http://www.marvelrealtors.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/Izara-site-plan.jpg" target="_self">
    <img src="http://www.marvelrealtors.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/Izara-site-plan.jpg" class=" vc_box_border_grey attachment-full" alt="layout" data-lazy-loaded="true" style="display: inline;"><noscript>&lt;img src="http://www.marvelrealtors.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/Izara-site-plan.jpg" class=" vc_box_border_grey attachment-full" alt="layout" /&gt;</noscript>
</a>
```

Comment: you can add url to href from image src.

Comment: actually this is coming from plugin I mentioned above. which have shortcode in backed on this page. This was working in few days ago. Now there is so many images in other pages. How to solve this?

Comment: Did you set featured image like others?

Comment: yes featured images just like others. I put Owl Carousel URL to # which in past was doing the same

Comment: I think featuresd images not set. make sure

Comment: if features images empty # is added in href by plugin

Comment: I have added featured image but in image url I added # since I was doing the same in past and it was working but not now

Comment: please remove # from image url and add url of featured image

Comment: I did that also removing # and adding featured image url also dont work.

Comment: I think I found the solution. what I did is added featured image url replaced with # and clear page cache. Now it is working. But is it temporary solution?

Comment: Owl Carousel is the plugin name

Answer (score -1):

The problem comes from file names, no accent, space or special character and it will work.